Bash script does not recognize filenames read from file while copying
I'm using a bash script to copy specific files listed in a file, into another directory. The issue is that those filenames are not being recognized as such and i get an error ' ' 'file not found'
The files do exist and I am in the correct directory.
Thing is if I use a list of filenames obtained by ls > list_of_files it works no issue (though this gives me all files and I only want specific ones). This also works if I write the filenames in by hand.
To the naked eye both file lists look the same, what could be the issue here? It kind of seems like it only reads part of the string as a filename or a space?
The structure of filenames is a such AAA-000.a_a.png
Below is the copying part of the script
while IFS= read -r file;do
 if [ -f "$file" ]; then
  cp "$file" "$destination"
 else
  echo "file '$file' not found"
 fi


Check your file for DOS/Windows carriage return line terminators.

See also why not parse the result of the ls command.

[edit] your question to show us the contents of the file (or pipe or whatever) you're reading the file names from and the undesirable output you're seeing given that input.

https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, why not parse ls

If you know that the file exist, don't test the existence, just copy. If the file really is not there, cp will complain about it. For debugging, do a xxd <<<$file to check that the variable indeed has a reasonable value.

In addition, do a pwd before entering the loop to verify, that you are looking into the right directory.

I'm with @thatotherguy This sounds suspiciiously like a CRLF problem. Use dos2unix filename to fix the input file.

@phuclv They're not parsing ls, they're trying to get the list from a file. The only mention of ls is that they were able to create the file successfully from it.

You said it works if you redirect ls to the file or create it by hand. How did you create the file if it wasn't one of those two methods?

@Barmar but the list of file is obtained by ls > list_of_files which suffers from the same issue
